# Custom environment with horizontal indentation

Tags: environments, indentation

I am trying to create a simple environment that consists two parts:

1. bold text followed by a rightarrow
2. (multiple) lines of text with indentation, below the bold text

What I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{subfig}

\newenvironment{myeventeq}[1]
  {\textbf{#1} $\Rightarrow$\vspace{1ex}\par
   \hspace*{2em}%%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2em}}
  {\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}    
  \subfloat[piece1]{  
    \begin{myeventeq}{piece of bold text}
      condition 1 to be satisfied\\
      condition 2 to be satisfied
    \end{myeventeq}
  }
  \subfloat[piece2]{
    \begin{myeventeq}{piece of bold text}
      condition 1 to be satisfied\\
      condition 2 to be satisfied
    \end{myeventeq}  
  }
  \caption{dual caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: example]

What is currently the problem is:

- the conditions should be below the piece of bold text
- the second subfigure falls of the page.

Comment: It would be nice if you listed the packages you're using.  Also, how exactly are things not working with `subfig`?  Could you post code in which it doesn't work as you expect?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the `list` environment, you could just make one environment for your structure build around a `minipage`.  The problem with this is that it will not break across pages.  But since you mentioned `subfig` I'm assuming that this environment isn't something that is intended to span multiple pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newenvironment{myeventeq}[1]
  {\textbf{#1} $\Rightarrow$\vspace{1ex}\par
   \hspace*{2em}%%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2em}}
  {\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

Hello

\begin{myeventeq}{piece of bold text}
  condition 1 to be satisfied\\
  condition 2 to be satisfied
\end{myeventeq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my example to a MWE. When I put the environment within a `subfig`, the second part is no longer below the bold text. Is there any way how I can fix this?